# Set up apache2 for an application

Tags: javascript, apache, web.py

I created an small web application using web.py. When deploying and accessing the application through the web browser I get an error related to the location of javascript files.

I followed the structure recommended in learnpythonthehardway.org, so I have the following:

```
   myapp/
        bin/
            app.py
        python_module/
            my_module.py
        static/
            javascript/
                myScript.js
        templates/
            index.html
```

Within index.html I have next line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript/myScript.js"></script>
```

I've uploaded the files to /var/www/html/myapp

In apache I have to following configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /var/www/html/myapp/bin/app.py

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Now, when I access http://example.com/myapp I got a 404 error because the application is looking for the javascript in http://example.com/static/javascript/myScript.js

What is the configuration to look for the javascript files in the right location, other than change the src attribute in the script tag within index.html?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript/myScript.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/static/javascript/myScript.js"></script>
```

It just is looking for an absolute url based on the root of the webserver.  `/static` means in `/var/www/html/static`.  You can also get rid of the first `/` if you want but you would have to be careful if you have any subdirectory handling otherwise it will try to find `static` inside that other directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to add the following line to apache configuration:

```
Alias /static /var/www/html/movies/static
```

As the apache documentation says:

"The Alias and ScriptAlias directives are used to map between URLs and filesystem paths"